# DynamoDB and ElasticSearch - table design approaches

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'am currently thinking about my DynamoDB database. The goal is to get the best speed with a really large amount of data possible. For me, DynamoDB seems as a good option. Furthermore, it is necessary for me to connect the table to ElasticSearch because I need geopoint-querys (like show me all posts that are within a specific area). 
Would the following approach make sense to you regarding the best practices of DynamoDB? It is possible, that the sort key for example 'posts' is a hot spot, but if I query only with ElasticSearch, there should be no problem - right? What would be the best solution?

My tables look like this: 
[image]

So my thoughts are:

- To query all users just select every row with the sort_key 'user'
- To get a post with the creator, query the post_id and the sort_key 'post'

In a relational database, the two tables would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like using overloaded attributes (using same columns for different things)
[image]

Then, query with user_id and post_id=0 for user info and post_id=others for posts

Answer (score 1):

I don't think dynamo DB is a good option for that. 
Limitation for `DynamoDB` listed below.

- You can't get more than 1 MB data per API call
- wildcard search will give you a poor performance
- Aggregation will be a nightmare since you plan for the huge data